# Is there a way to translate or migrate prg (foxpro) to sql language?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, foxpro

I have some programs (.prg) that operate using .dbf files, as i am migrating to postgresql (personal preferences) i really would like to know if there are ways to "translate" commands from one language to another.
Translating to python would be another possibility
Thank you

Comment: The PostgreSQL wiki lists translation and conversion tools: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL . For something as niche as Visual FoxPro, I rather doubt it, though, especially since it's more of a RAD framework than just a database.

Comment: all right, i will go to the translation tools though

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. Visual FoxPro the language is fairly tightly tied into its own object model, and when you start bringing UI elements into the equation the time and work involved in automatic migration means that it's always quicker to re-implement on the new platform.

If you're interested in Python you could take a look at [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/). This is a Python framework aimed at desktop and web apps, but developed by some long-time Visual FoxPro experts. In that respect it is conceptually similar to Visual FoxPro in a lot of ways.

> Dabo's authors, Ed Leafe and Paul McNett, have strong backgrounds in
>   database application development using the awesome and underrated
>   Microsoft Visual FoxPro development environment.
>
> While Visual FoxPro shines at developing data-centric applications, it
>   has one limitation that cannot be ignored: it only runs on Microsoft
>   Windows, and Ed and Paul both have clients that want their
>   applications to run on Linux and Macintosh. We are sure we are not
>   alone in this regard: it is a multi-platform world with more diverse
>   needs than one vendor can fulfill.
>
> Ed and Paul got to talking one day: Paul had been researching various
>   multiplatform GUI toolkits for about 18 months, and Ed has lots of
>   experience developing the Visual FoxPro Codebook framework. We decided
>   to work together to make a framework for developing robust
>   data-centric applications for multi-platform deployment. We've come up
>   with a design that is simple, flexible, and robust, and we've begun
>   developing our own client applications using the Dabo framework.

Comment: I will check dabo. I keep the question open anyway.